# Can Kate recognize two coding language comment styles in the same document/script?

Tags: kate

I realize this may be asking too much of any text editor but was wondering if there is a way to have Kate recognize comment symbols for more than one coding language in the same script.

I'm using Tcl and setting some SQL queries is a separate `::SQL::` namespace. I can't put `#` comments within the SQL text because when the SQL is processed that will be treated as text and error. I can use the `--` or `/*...*/` comments in the SQL text but they are not recognized by Kate as Tcl comments and blend in with the rest of the SQL code.

It's not very important but, some times, it's surprising what they develop and I don't know can be done in an application.

Thank you.

An example is:

```
# Regular Tcl comment

set ::SQL::QueryName {
  SELECT ...
  -- this works but is not styled as comment.
  # This is styled as comment but errors when
  # attempt to execute the SQL.
}
``
```

Comment: Not AFAIK. Given similar situations, I'd save the SQL in one document and Tcl in another, with a placeholder for SQL, to get the benefits of syntax highlighting and checking in each, then merge the files manually.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you for the response and suggestion.

Comment: You might be able to copy and extend an existing language definition and add support https://api.kde.org/frameworks/syntax-highlighting/html/#syntax-definition-files